# Django admin inline has 2 foreign keys to the same model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Currently i have the transfer model as followed:

```
class Transfers(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "transfers"
        verbose_name = 'Transfer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Transfers'
user = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_transfer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

to_account = models.ForeignKey("backend.User", null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_transfer_to_account', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

A transfer object need to have from one user transfer to another user so i need to use the same User model

And in my admin.py:

```
class TransfersInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Transfers

    can_delete = False
    extra = 0
    max_num=0

    form = TransfersAdminForm

class UserAdminCustom(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ('password', 'last_login', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'groups',
               'user_permissions', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_active', 'date_joined')

    inlines = [
        TransfersInline,
    ]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(UserAdminCustom, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_staff=False)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return ('id', 'created', 'modified')


admin.site.register(User, UserAdminCustom)
```

In my admin i would like to display transfers inline that the User existed in `user` field of `Transfers` model but inline can't have multiple foreign key to the same model:

```
<class 'backend.admin.TransfersInline'>: (admin.E202) 'backend.Transfers' has more than one ForeignKey to 'backend.User'
```

My question is how do i only make TransfersInline use foreign key from `user` field instead of `to_account` field ? (transfer inline will have all the transfers object that the User is in user field )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fk_name='user'` option for `TransfersInline` class.

[You can check the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model)